# aria2c fails to download to a path that is mounted to FTP

Tags: linux, ftp, mount, aria2

I would like to setup a downloader on a raspberry PI to download into my NAS (MyBookLive), since I don't have enough space on the PI. I don't want to install the downloader into the MyBookLive since it is running out of CPU and MEM already.

**1.** I've mounted the NAS through FTP to the PI with the instructions that can be found if you follow the [link](https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem). Basically I did:

```
curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp-user:ftp-pass@my-ftp-location.local /mnt/entresol/Public
```

I am able to copy files back and forth `/mnt/entresol/Public`:

```
cp README.md /mnt/antresol/Public/temp/
```

**2.** I've installed `aria2` and I am able to download a file to a PI dir:

```
aria2c -d ~/aria2c/ ~/aria2c.log https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md
```

But when I try download to an FTP mounted dir:

```
aria2c -d /mnt/antresol/Public/ ~/aria2c.log https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md
```

I receive following error:

```
12/12 22:32:46 [ERROR] CUID#6 - Download aborted. URI=https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:350] errorCode=16 URI=https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md
  -> [AbstractDiskWriter.cc:222] errNum=95 errorCode=16 Failed to open the file /mnt/antresol/Public/temp/README.md, cause: Operation not supported
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't mount ftp.

Comment: Why not use NFS, or Samba or some other protocol that is designed to work for network storage..  (do people really still use ftp??)   If you just need to move files automagically and / or keep them in sync... rsync is light and does a pretty good job too

Comment: I don't think MyBookLive has either Samba or NFS, but if there is no other way, probably I can try to install them. Thank you

Comment: Try to turn off file allocation in aria2c by using option [`--file-allocation=none`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-file-allocation). MyBookLive provides samba shares, I use it from Windows.

Comment: Tried ```aria2c --file-allocation=none -d /mnt/antresol/Public/ https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md``` - same issue. But at the same time I found that NFS is working on MyBookLive so the following command works: ```sudo mount -t nfs user:pass@my-ftp-location.local:/nfs/Public /mnt/antresol/Public/``` and ```aria2c -d /mnt/mbl/Public/ https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2/blob/master/README.md``` works fine. DDeMartini and Alexei Ivanov please post it as answer and I will accept.